# Vue js multiple instances of module

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Not sure if this question is appropriately titled.  I am using Vue 2 and somewhat noob at it (it's my third day).  I have a basic app with product pages.  My payment system is through Stripe.

I'm using the npm module here https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-stripe

If I browse around the site and click on a few products it seems like it is creating more and more instances of Stripe, because when I go to make a purchase, it makes the same amount of calls as number of times I clicked on product pages.

So if I only visit once product page, the stripe api only gets called once, on my second visit to a product page the stripe api gets called twice when I make a purchase, and so on.

The other thing is if I refresh the page by hitting the browser reload button it resets itself and only loads the one instance of Stripe.

My product.vue page has the following format

```js
<html stuff at top>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { StripeCheckout, Bus} from 'vue-stripe'
export default {
  components: {
    'stripe-checkout': StripeCheckout
  },
  created () {
  Bus.$on('vue-stripe.success', payload => {
    // do stuff with payload
  })
}
  // more logic here
}
</script>
```

The console is not giving me any clues, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem, it looks hard to understand without more code (e.g. how <stripe-checkout> tag is used) but I can suggest debugging. You can put `debugger` lines to the code to debug the critical parts like the handler of 'vue-stripe.success' event. Also do you use VueJS chrome extension, which is handy for debugging. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's happening because you're not properly removing the component from the DOM between different app states (though you think you do).

1. Check your `v-if`s, sometimes you can notice some redundancy on their conditions.
2. Be sure you're not allowing `Bus` instance to register the same even handler twice, thus calling `Bus.$off` on every destroy hook in the lifecycle.

Example:

```
export default {
  components: {
    StripeCheckout
  },
  methods: {
    onStripeSuccess (payload) {
      // do stuff with payload
    }
  },
  created () {
    Bus.$on('vue-stripe.success', this.onStripeSuccess)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    Bus.$off('vue-stripe.success')
  }
}
```

More on this:

Component lifecycle: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Removing event listeners: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off